# Maple: having params[1]; returning 'a[0] = 2' how to make a[0] = 2?

Tags: arrays, evaluation, maple

So I have some array called `params[];` there are  things like `a[0] = 2` in it. I want to make all such items real meaning I would call a[0]; and get 2. How to do such thing in maple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not the only ways to accomplish your goal. But hopefully they'll guide you.

One ways is to handle each such equation (from `params`) individually.

```
restart:
params := array(1..3):
params[1] := a[0]=2:

params[1];
                        a[0] = 2

a[0];
                          a[0]

assign(params[1]);

a[0];
                           2
```

You might have all entries of `params` being equations, and wish to accomplish the same task for all entries, at once.

```
restart:
params := array(1..3):
params[1] := a[0]=2:
params[3] := a[5]=7:

params[1];
                        a[0] = 2

a[0], a[5];
                       a[0], a[5]

entries(params);
                 [a[0] = 2], [a[5] = 7]

assign(entries(params));

a[0], a[5];
                          2, 7
```

Or, you might wish to use uppercase Array instead of the lowercase array (which is deprecated in modern Maple).

```
restart:
params := Array(1..3):
params[1] := a[0]=2:
params[3] := a[5]=7:

params[1];
                        a[0] = 2

a[0], a[5];
                       a[0], a[5]

map(rhs,rtable_elems(params));
                  {a[0] = 2, a[5] = 7}

assign(%);

a[0],a[5];
                          2, 7
```

Or you might have some entries of `params` being equations, and others being some other type (mere scalar expressions, say). In that case you might first select those which as equations, and only assign using that subset.